# How many grams of CH3OH can be made from 30.0g of CO if it all reacts?

Tags: concentration

Once made by heating wood in the absence of air, methanol ($\ce{CH3OH}$) is now made by reacting carbon monoxide and hydrogen at high pressure: 
$\ce{CO_{(g)} + 2 H2_{(g)} -> CH3OH_{(l)}}$

How many grams of $\ce{CH3OH}$ can be made from 30.0g of $\ce{CO}$ if it all reacts?

Comment: Hi Brian, try recall the mole concept and show us your efforts we have to follow our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1):

Moles of CO in equals moles of methanol out (at 100% yield), typically over copper-doped zinc oxide catalyst.  Do the arithmetic.

One gram-mole of a chemical formula is [the magnitude of its atomic mass units] grams.  A nitrogen atom is 14.0067 amu.  A mole of nitrogen gas, $\ce{N2}$, is then 28.0134 grams.